# Setting Firebase config using environment variables

Tags: firebase, webpack, environment-variables, firebase-hosting

Currently, I have a static Firebase config object defined, and I am using a staging project for testing my deployed site in a mirrored production environment by using `firebase use --add`.

However, the staging site still references my main production app database. I want to link the staging app deployment to a staging app database, not the production app database for testing.

I was told I can use environment variables to achieve this in webpack, but am unclear of how to achieve this.

Comment: If you've follow the [approach outlined in this blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/07/deploy-to-multiple-environments-with.html), you'll have completely separate settings for both sites. If you're having trouble making it work, share the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: frank , I have followed that blog post to link an alternate staging app to test hosting before deploying hosting to production app. but in my App I am using hard coded config = {} values for my production app when calling `firebase.initializeApp(config)`. What I want to achieve is have a different config passed to `firebase.initializeApp(config)` when i'm deploying to my staging app and different config when deploying to my production app. Currently, I'm solving this by commenting and uncommenting code of the two different configs.

Comment: I think the question asked is pretty clear. ```firebase use``` will change the project that gets deployed but what is the best practice for changing the config string so you can connect to a different database per project.